# Global hook DLL only calls C# callback method when the C# main window is active/foreground

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, callback, hook

I have a C# app that opens a C++ global key hook. The dll listens to key presses globally, and calls the main app callback method when a certain key is pressed.

The dll hook process works, except that it does not call the callback function when the main application is not the active screen, which is pointless at this state. Is there a work around for this? I may be missing something.

C# code:

```
//Global Key DLL callback delegate
public delegate void KeyCallBackFunction(int keyPoints);

[DllImport("Dll1_64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void SetCallBack(IntPtr pCallBack);

IntPtr hInstance = IntPtr.Zero;
private delegate void HookSetting();


private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

...

KeyCallBackFunction keyPointDelegate = new KeyCallBackFunction(DetectKey);
// Use GCHandle to hold the delegate object in memory.
GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(keyPointDelegate);
// Obtain an unmanaged function pointer for the delegate as usual.
IntPtr intptr_delegate = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(keyPointDelegate);

// Callback is setup as a thread
Thread keyThread= new Thread(() => SetCallBack(intptr_delegate));
keyThread.Start();


// Global hook Setup
hInstance = LoadLibrary("Dll1_64");
hProc = GetProcAddress(hInstance, "SetHook");
HookSetting hookset = (HookSetting)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(hProc, typeof(HookSetting));
hookset();

}

public static void DetectKey(int point)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (keyPoints == 0)
        {
            // do something for key point zero
        }
        else
        {
            // do something for other key points
        }
    }));
}
```

C++ Global Key hook dll:

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
//these variables will be shared among all processes to which this dll is linked
#pragma data_seg("Shared")
//our hook handle which will be returned by calling SetWindowsHookEx function
HHOOK hkKey = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInstHookDll = NULL;  //our global variable to store the instance of our DLL
#pragma data_seg() //end of our data segment

#pragma comment(linker,"/section:Shared,rws")
// Tell the compiler that Shared section can be read,write and shared

HWND pHWnd = NULL;

typedef void(__stdcall* PCallBack)(int points);

PCallBack g_pCallBack = NULL;

// used to register callback
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SetCallBack(PCallBack pCallBack)
{
    g_pCallBack = pCallBack;
}

// call callbacak function
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall PerformAction(int points)
{
    if (g_pCallBack)
    {
        g_pCallBack(points);
    }
}

//this is the hook procedure
__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK procCharMsg(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //a pointer to hold the MSG structure that is passed as lParam
    MSG* msg;
    //to hold the character passed in the MSG structure's wParam
    char charCode;
    if (nCode >= 0 && nCode == HC_ACTION)
        //if nCode is less than 0 or nCode
        //is not HC_ACTION we will call CallNextHookEx
    {
        //lParam contains pointer to MSG structure.
        msg = (MSG*)lParam;
        if (msg->message == WM_CHAR)
        {
            charCode = msg->wParam;
            if (IsCharLower(charCode))
                //we check if the character pressed is a small letter
            {
                //if so, make it to capital letter
                charCode -= 32;
                msg->wParam = (WPARAM)charCode;
                //overwrite the msg structure's wparam 
                //with our new value. 
            }

            if (charCode == 'A') {
                PerformAction(0); // Point Zero
            }
            else if (charCode == 'B') {
                PerformAction(1); // Point One
            }
            else {
                PerformAction(2); // Point Two
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hkKey, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SetHook()
 {
     if (hkKey == NULL)
         hkKey = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, procCharMsg, hInstHookDll, 0);
 }

 //remove the hook
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall RemoveHook()
 {
     if (hkKey != NULL)
         UnhookWindowsHookEx(hkKey);
     hkKey = NULL;
 }

 INT APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved) {

     switch (Reason)
     {
     case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
         //we initialize our variable with the value that is passed to us
         hInstHookDll = (HINSTANCE)hDLL;
         break;
     default:
         break;
     }
     return TRUE;
 }
```

EDIT: I changed my approach to a shared HWND pointer to the mainwindow. Then simply sending/posting a message to that HWND allows me to receive the info via WndProc

Comment: I think the Invoke is preventing cross strapping so it is only allowing the code to run when the window is active.  Try removing the Invoke.  I do not think you want to stop the method from cross strapping errors, only the data needs to be protected from cross strapping issues.

Comment: @jdweng I tried to run it without the invoke and unfortunately, it seems to behave the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A global hook gets loaded into every running process, meaning every process will have its own individual copy of the DLL loaded in it.

The hook DLL is accounting for that by storing the `HHOOK` handle in a shared data segment for all processes to share. But the `g_pCallBack` variable is not stored in that segment, so it is not being shared. Only the original process that actually calls `SetCallback()` will have its `g_pCallBack` assigned, and thus only keyboard activity in that process will be reported to the callback.

You can't store `g_pCallBack` in the shared segment, either, since a raw function pointer can't be called across process boundaries. You would need to use an inter-process communication framework like COM or RPC to do that.

A simple solution would be to replace `g_pCallBack` with an `HWND` stored in the shared segment, and then the hook loaded into each process can post window messages to the `HWND` when needed. The C# app can allocate a window to receive those messages, and give that window to its copy of the DLL to store in the shared segment. Or, if you want to keep using a `delegate` then have `SetHook()` create is own `HWND` and then have the window handler call the delegate if assigned.

Comment: The shared `HWND` is what I went for, and it worked. Thanks a lot mate.